# Blacktriangleright too large with stix

Tags: symbols, scaling, stix

I'd like to create a smaller `\blacktriangleright` using stix.

I tried with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[\blacktriangleright,\Scale[0.75]{\blacktriangleright}\]
\end{document}
```

But the result is this: Unfortunately `\Scale[0.75]{\blacktriangleright}` is a little below than `\blacktriangleright`, this is, if I draw a line from `\Scale[0.75]{\blacktriangleright}`'s tip to `\blacktriangleright` one, this line is oblique, or, these tips are not aligned.

I'd like to create a LaTeX function that resize #1, where #1 is an object, for example, `\blacktriangleright`, or something else e. g. `\sum,\prod,\int,\oiiint`, ... .

How could I do?

I accept any suggestions.

Comment: Apart from the typos that I tried to fix, what's the definition of `\Scale`? Please, try the examples before posting them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guessed a definition for `\Scale`.

Quite likely you want to `\vcenter` the scaled symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Scale}[2][1]{\scalebox{#1}{$\m@th#2$}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\sblacktriangleright}{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\Scale[0.75]{\blacktriangleright}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\blacktriangleright,\sblacktriangleright
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A possible improvement. I define a `\Scalecenter` macro that centers vertically the symbol, but also changes size appropriately depending on the math style (for subscripts and superscripts, for instance).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Scalecenter}[2][1]{\mathpalette\Scalecenter@{{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\Scalecenter@}[2]{\Scalecenter@@#1#2}
\newcommand{\Scalecenter@@}[3]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#2}{$\m@th#1#3$}}}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\sblacktriangleright}{%
  \Scalecenter[0.75]{\blacktriangleright}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\blacktriangleright,\sblacktriangleright
\quad
\scriptstyle
\blacktriangleright,\sblacktriangleright
\quad
\scriptscriptstyle
\blacktriangleright,\sblacktriangleright
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some more work would be needed for also setting the appropriate math type.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Scalecenter}[3]{#1{\mathpalette\Scalecenter@{{#2}{#3}}}}
\newcommand{\Scalecenter@}[2]{\Scalecenter@@#1#2}
\newcommand{\Scalecenter@@}[3]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#2}{$\m@th#1#3$}}}%
}

\newcommand{\sblacktriangleright}{%
  \Scalecenter{\mathord}{0.75}{\blacktriangleright}%
}
\newcommand{\ssum}{%
  \DOTSB\Scalecenter{\mathop}{0.75}{\sum}\slimits@
}
\newcommand{\sotimes}{\Scalecenter{\mathbin}{0.5}{\otimes}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\blacktriangleright,\sblacktriangleright
\quad
\scriptstyle
\blacktriangleright,\sblacktriangleright
\quad
\scriptscriptstyle
\blacktriangleright,\sblacktriangleright
\]
\[
\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\otimes y_k \quad \ssum_{k=1}^n x_k\sotimes y_k
\]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Possibly you don't know what `\DOTSB` and `\slimits@` are for. They're necessary to keep in synch with `amsmath`.

Comment: Thaank you very much. I use often **DOTSB** and possibibly also **\slimits**.

Answer (score 3):

May be try something like that, to resize what You want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\resizebox{.4\textwidth}{!}{$\dot{\rho}=
\dfrac{x^3}{45a^9-23b}$}
\end{document}
```

Or if You want to make it command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\res}[2]{\resizebox{#1\textwidth}{!}{#2}}

\begin{document}
\res{0.5}{$\dot{\rho}=
\dfrac{x^3}{45a^9-23b}$}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `\smallblacktriangleright`.