# A version of \blacktriangleright that looks the same as \triangleright

Tags: symbols

**Please see the note at the end before voting to close. This is not a duplicate of the linked question and the answers there do not help with this one.**

I'm looking for a symbol that goes together nicely with `\triangleright`, to indicate a similar but different relation. I thought that `\blacktriangleright` from the `amssymb` package would do the job, but it turns out to be a different size and shape from `\triangleright`:

[image]

Is there another symbol somewhere that looks just like `\triangleright` only filled in?

Alternatively, I'd be happy to take other suggestions for some other variation on the `\triangleright` theme that could be used to suggest another relation of the same type.

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

$A\triangleright B$ vs. $A\blacktriangleright B$

\end{document}
```

---

About the supposed duplicate: I admit that the question [Blacktriangleright too large with stix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619225/blacktriangleright-too-large-with-stix?noredirect=1&lq=1) does sound at first glance to be similar to mine. However, that question is about how to take an existing glyph and scale it by a given amount. That would not help in my case, because `\blacktriangleright` is not only bigger than `\triangleright`, it is also a different shape. So if I would try to solve my problem by scaling `\blacktriangleright` I would end up with a triangle of approximately the right size but the wrong proportions and it would look bad. Consequently **that question is asking for a different thing and the answers to it do not help with my question**. This is not a duplicate. (Sorry for the bold text but I'm still getting close votes even after having explained this.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blacktriangleright too large with stix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619225/blacktriangleright-too-large-with-stix)

Comment: @AlanMunn that gives a way to manually resize the symbol, but it's still not going to be the same shape as the `\triangleright` one. The title might sound similar but it's a completely different question.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but amssymb defined `\vartriangleright` which has the same dimensions as `\blacktriangleright`. So perhaps you could use that instead of `\triangleright`?

Comment: @Slurp that's helpful - I could use that, but I do prefer the look of `\triangleright`.

Comment: Why is this attracting close votes? I've explained why the other answer doesn't help. (It really doesn't!)

Comment: @N.Virgo "approximately the right size but the wrong proportions": you can use different scaling factors for the horizontal and vertical directions

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz this is true, and it would be one way to solve my problem, but I'm hoping an appropriate symbol already exists in some package somewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can resize `\blacktriangleright` to match `\triangleright` (with a small horizontal shift).

In the code below I assume that what you want are relation symbols, notwithstanding that `\triangleright` is classed as operation symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}% just for the final comparison

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tleft}{\mathrel\triangleleft}
\newcommand{\tright}{\mathrel\triangleright}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\btleft}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\btlr@\blacktriangleleft}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\btright}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\btlr@\blacktriangleright}}

\newcommand{\btlr@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\triangleright$}%
  \sbox\tw@{\resizebox{1.1\wd\z@}{1.1\ht\z@}{\raisebox{\depth}{$\m@th#1\mkern-1mu#2$}}}%
  \ht\tw@=\ht\z@ \dp\tw@=\dp\z@ \wd\tw@=\wd\z@
  \copy\tw@
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

$A \tright B \btright C$ $A\tleft B\btleft C$

$A \btright B \tright C$ $A\btleft B\tleft C$

{\ooalign{$\tright$\cr\color{red}$\btright$\cr}}
{\ooalign{$\btright$\cr\color{red}$\tright$\cr}}

{\ooalign{$\scriptstyle\tright$\cr\color{red}$\scriptstyle\btright$\cr}}
{\ooalign{$\scriptstyle\btright$\cr\color{red}$\scriptstyle\tright$\cr}}


{\fboxsep=0pt \fboxrule=0.1pt \fbox{$\tright$} \fbox{$\btright$}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The comparison with the different colors shows that the superimposition is not really perfect, but the differences are really tiny and not noticeable when the symbols are separate.